# Django 1.5 employee-management where some employees can login some can't

Tags: django, model

So I want to keep track of about 100 employees but only five of them should be able to log in into the backend (the rest starts with no loginpossibilities at all) what's the best way to solve that problem ?

I thought of an EmployeeModel that has a 1to1-relation to an abstractBaseUser but is that the way to go or is there something easier ?

~Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make use of [Django 1.5's new customisable `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#configurable-user-model) and model each employee as a user with an extended profile:

> In Django 1.5, you can now use your own model as the store for user-related data. If your project needs a username with more than 30 characters, or if you want to store user’s names in a format other than first name/last name, or you want to put custom profile information onto your User object, you can now do so.

By making each employee a "user", you have the balance of being able to control their ability to login (using [`is_staff`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff)) as well as being able to add as much employee profile information that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have FK from employee to user if an employee has an attached account?

Comment: but in the user model are forname and lastname also .. isn't that redundant ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for over customisation as this can be easily achieved easily using the built-in tools. Make the login_page require a permission suppose say "can login". And just make these 5 users have those permission. So rest will automatically get a  permission denied response when trying to login.